# How to compare an object in a LinkedList to an integer

Tags: java, linked-list

```
public static LinkedList checkMaze(int r, int c, LinkedList t, int i)
 {
   int temp = t.get(i);

    if(temp == 1)
    {
      System.out.println("You've hit a wall in the maze, try a different move!");
      System.out.print("Enter a point in the maze: (row, col)");
      r = getInt();
      c = getInt();
      i = findIndex(r, c, t);
    }
    t.set(i, "+");
    return t;
 }
```

I'm trying to see if whatever is in the list at the specified location is equal to 1 but can't think of a way to accomplish that. The list consists of 1's and 0's.

The error that shows up is "Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.lang.Object to int" at "int temp = t.get(i);"

Comment: What error have you got with this code?

Comment: Are you not able to read the values for r and c from console?

Comment: Why is it just a `LinkedList` and not a `LinkedList<Integer>` (or something like that)?

Comment: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.lang.Object to int" this is the error that shows up. @armnotstrong

Comment: @confusedprogammer why do you have a plain `LinkedList` and not a `LinkedList<Integer>`?

Comment: You can do a *cast* if you are pretty sure that the `LinkedList` always contains a `Integer`, but it's strongly recommended that you don't do that. Involving the type with `LinkedList<Integer>` as people here adviced.

Comment: And modern IDE should warn you that. Isn't there any warning in your IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to see if whatever is in the list at the specified location
>   is equal to 1

I suppose your List is a List of Integer so change this line

```
public static LinkedList checkMaze(int r, int c, LinkedList t, int i)
```

to

```
public static LinkedList<Integer> checkMaze(int r, int c, LinkedList<Integer> t, int i)
```

then simply verify if the value is equal to 1

```
if(t.get(i) == 1)
```

---

Another solution would consist in specifying that the Object is an Integer.

```
int temp = (Integer)t.get(i);
```

but I prefer the first one as you won't have to repeat each time.

Comment: Even the return type should have a generic I guess?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe u cloud like this:

```
Integer valueInList =  Integer.parseInt(_linkedList.get(compareIndex).toString);
//YOUR COMPARE RULE
if(compareVale == valueInList ){
    system.out.println("the are equals.");
}
```